# TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: flutter, httprequest

The error is at user p = await createuser() inside Raisedbutton onpressed function

I have added toString() at the end of mobileinputcontroller while passing parameter to user.dart inside Raisedbutton onpressed function, still i am getting the above error.
What else should be done?

Here is the code:

```
Future<User> createUser (String url,{Map body}) async{

    String userId;

    return http.post(url,
          body:body).then((http.Response response){
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
    }

    print(json.decode(response.body));

    var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
    userId = extractdata["uid"];
    print(userId);
    return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    });

  }


class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> implements RegisterPageContract{

  BuildContext _ctx;
  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool loading = false;
  RegisterPagePresenter _presenter;
  User newUser;

  static final create_url = "http://www.hiddenmasterminds.com/web/index.php?r=featured/createinitialstudent";
  TextEditingController firstNameInputController;
  TextEditingController lastNameInputController;
  TextEditingController emailInputController;
  TextEditingController pwdInputController;
  TextEditingController confirmPwdInputController;
  TextEditingController mobileNoInputController;
  TextEditingController referCodeInputController;

  @override
  initState() {

    firstNameInputController = new TextEditingController();
    lastNameInputController = new TextEditingController();
    mobileNoInputController = new TextEditingController();
    emailInputController = new TextEditingController();
    pwdInputController = new TextEditingController();
    confirmPwdInputController = new TextEditingController();
    referCodeInputController = new TextEditingController();


    super.initState();

    _presenter = RegisterPagePresenter(this);
  }

  void _submit(){
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if(form.validate()){
      loading = true;
      form.save();
      _presenter.doRegister(firstNameInputController.text.toString(),
          firstNameInputController.text.toString(),
          emailInputController.text.toString(),
          mobileNoInputController.text.toString(),
          pwdInputController.text.toString(),
          "comp",
          "sppu",
          "pict",
          "abc",
          "123",
          "cdv" );
        }
  }

  String error = '';
  bool _showPassword = false;
  bool _showConfirmPassword = false;
  bool checkBoxValue = true;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pwdInputController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  String emailValidator(String value) {
    Pattern pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Email Format Is Invalid';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  String pwdValidator(String value) {
    if (value.length < 8) {
      return 'Password Must Be Longer Than 8 Characters';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  String confirmPwdValidator(String val) {
    if(val.isEmpty)
      return 'Empty';
    if(val != pwdInputController.text)
      return "Password Doesn't Match";
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _ctx = context;
    final bgColor = const Color(0xFF4b0081);
    return loading ? Loading() : Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
      body:SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:30.0, right: 30, left: 30, bottom: 100),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 25.0,),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) {
                      if (val.length < 3) {
                        return "Enter a Valid First Name";
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "First and Last Name",
                        hintText: "John Joe",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.perm_identity,
                          color: Colors.blue[400],
                        )
                    ),
                    controller: firstNameInputController,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                  ),

                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) => val.length != 10 ? "Enter a 10 Digit Mobile Number" : null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.phone_android,
                          color: Colors.blue[400],
                        ),
                        labelText: "10 Digit Mobile Number(for OTP)",
                        hintText: "94XXXXXX12",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                    ),
                    controller: mobileNoInputController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) => emailValidator(val),
                    controller: emailInputController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.mail,
                          color: Colors.blue[400],
                        ),
                        labelText: "Email ID",
                        hintText: "john.doe@gmail.com",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) => pwdValidator(val),
                    controller: pwdInputController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          color: Colors.blue[400],
                        ),
                        labelText: "Passoword",
                        hintText: "********",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                  setState(() {
                  _showPassword = !_showPassword;
                  });
                  },
                      child: Icon(
                        _showPassword ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                        color: Colors.blue[400],
                      )
                  ),
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                    obscureText: !_showPassword,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) => confirmPwdValidator(val),
                    controller: confirmPwdInputController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          color: Colors.blue[400],
                        ),
                        suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              setState(() {
                                _showConfirmPassword = !_showConfirmPassword;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              _showConfirmPassword ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                              color: Colors.blue[400],
                            )
                        ),
                        labelText: "Confirm Passoword",
                        hintText: "********",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                    obscureText: !_showConfirmPassword,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(

                    controller: referCodeInputController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.insert_emoticon,
                          color: Colors.blue[400],
                        ),
                        labelText: "Refer Code(If Any)",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Checkbox(
                        value: checkBoxValue,
                        onChanged: (bool value){
                          setState(() {
                            checkBoxValue = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      Text('By Clicking This You Agree All The Terms and Conditions.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 10
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),

                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(
                      'Register',
                      style: TextStyle(color: bgColor),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {

                      newUser = new User(firstName:firstNameInputController.text.toString(), 
                      lastName: lastNameInputController.text.toString(),emailId:emailInputController.text.toString(),
                mobile: mobileNoInputController.text.toString(),password: pwdInputController.text.toString(),
                department: "comp",univ_name: "abc",college_name: "hello",
                university_year: "234",build_no: "234",android_no: "asd");

                      User p = await createUser(create_url,body:newUser.toMap());
                      // _submit();

                    },
                    splashColor: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
                  Text(
                    error,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 14.0
                    ),
                  ),

                  FlatButton(
                    color: bgColor,
                    child: Text(
                      'Already Have An Account? Login Here!',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(_ctx, './SignIn');
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Please help to resolve the problem!!

Comment: Where do you get the error ? Is this code in the same repository 'sql' ?

Comment: No its different. And i am getting an exception at try{ return await fn client}

Comment: i have added image of the error. Please check the edited question

Comment: Thanks. Couldn’t reproduce the issue. :-( Does the problem occur all the time. Are all the user input fields correctly validated ?

Comment: On the user tap, you don’t seem to check if the form state is validated, typically - _formKey.currentState.validate()

Comment: on the user tap ? i didn't get you

Comment: In Register button's onPressed event, you are not checking if the input is correct. Not sure if it's a good idea (and also not sure if this is causing a problem). Does the problem occur all the time i.e. even on valid input ?

Comment: yess,now i have even tried sending as string and not take input. Its showing same error

Comment: i solved the error . it was in user.dart. thanks for the help anyways!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
userId = extractdata["uid"].toString();
```